# Discord.py logging system is not allowing me to download files, raising an HTTPException

Tags: python, discord.py

I have made a logging system, that stores information in text files. I know how I can send files, however, the log system prevents sending files that were made the same day, and raises an error saying I cannot send empty messages. I will post here a code for the on_message, some other needed commands, and the log download command.

```
async def append_new_line(self, guildid, text_to_append):
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    date_time = today.strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
    with open(f"./Logs/{guildid}/{date_time}.txt", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as a:
        a.write(f"\n{text_to_append}")

async def create_log(self):
    date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
    for guild in self.bot.guilds:
        try:
            with open(f"./Logs/{guild.id}/{date_time}.txt", "x"): 
                await self.append_new_line(guild.id, "[Time in CET][Message type][Name/ID][Channel ID]> ['Message', 'Link to attachment (if sent)' > 'New edited message (if message was edited)']\n")
        except FileExistsError:
            print("Log exists for all given guilds.\n")

async def create_guild_logs(self, guildid):
    path = f"./Logs/{guildid}"
    os.mkdir(path)

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_guild_join(self, guild:discord.Guild):
    self.create_guild_logs(guild.id)

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    await self.create_log()

### Logging messages starts here \/

@commands.Cog.listener()
@commands.guild_only()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author == self.bot.user: return
    else:
        author = message.author
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        time_detail = now.strftime("%Hh/%Mm/%Ss")
        if not message.attachments: await self.append_new_line(message.guild.id, f"[{time_detail}][Sent][{author}/{author.id}][{message.channel.id}]> ['{message.content}']")
        else: await self.append_new_line(message.guild.id, f"[{time_detail}][{author}/{author.id}][Sent][{message.channel.id}]> ['{message.content}', '{message.attachments[0].url}']")

### Log download \/

@commands.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def logdownload(self, ctx, date):
    date = date.replace("/","_")
    try:
        logfile = discord.File(f"./Logs/{ctx.guild.id}/{date}.txt")
        await ctx.send(file = logfile)
    except discord.HTTPException: pass
```

I want it to work like this "[prefix]logdownload 28/04/2021" and the bot will send the file of the day specified. You can see where the log is being stored in the append_new_line function. The files can also be downloaded the same day they were created.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send) you can find out that either the `content` or `embed` parameter have to be set.

Try adding

```
await ctx.send(content = "some text", file = logfile)
```

to your code.
You should also check if your logfile was actually found or not.

Comment: The docs do say that, but I have tested and you are able to send a file with no content or embed field.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. My theory is that when the log is appending to the text file, it doesn't actually saving it, until it creates a new file to append to (next day). When I try to save it, the program says that it's still being used.

Comment: Did you check `if logfile == None`?

Comment: I did now, the logfile exists, but It's still returning an error

Comment: I realized I didn't say the issue right. I updated the thread. TL;DR: I can send the files, but not the files made the same day

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `File` object incorrectly. You have to give it a file, not just a filename. Here is an example of how to use it properly:

```py
import discord

with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=f))
```

Comment: Still the same error: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message